# Python: Use multiple python windows for a same program

Tags: python, shell, multiprocessing, shared-libraries, multiple-instances

Is there a way to have a python program being able to open and manage multiple terminal windows? Like, in my script, making two windows open, and when I write something in the first one, like with

```
d = input()
```

it prints it in the second one? I'd like to avoid using sockets if possible, and avoid using python GUI libraries like Tkinter... But if there's no other way it's okay, just avoid it if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure how to open a new terminal, because it depends on your system, but look at the multiprocessing library wich is in the box with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!!

1) you can save your input_output data in a file and use it on another python script ( realtime ).

2) you can use multiprocessing module for handling multi process read more on:
https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

3) you can use Multithreaded module for handling multi thread, read more on :https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

4) you can use sys and subprocess modules for using pip port